# How can I find out what a previous commit has done?

Tags: git

I switched to a feature branch that I was working on and has been merged into the master branch.

I wanted to find out what changes I made on that branch, compared to the commit from which I created the branch and on which my work was based.

What commands can I use to find out that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a diff with the actual commit ids to see the difference between any two commits in the same branch.  You can use this format

```
git diff [or difftool] {first commit id} {second commit id} [optional path\filename]
```

e.g.

```
git difftool 9055ab693fdb1d63b76860b14bc21471e2fafae2 3f2a0e392d868e1af479e44fd6e4385e1b958574 folder\index.html
```

from gitdiff man page [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)

Comment: Thanks. I created my feature branch from the main branch. Does the commit on the main branch from which I created my feature branch belong to my feature branch? I want to compare what I has done on my branch compared to that commit on the main branch.

Answer (score 1):

If your branch was created from `master`, then use the following command:

```
git diff master...your_branch
```

> `git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]`
>
> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the
>      second `<commit>`, starting
>      at a common ancestor of both `<commit>`s. "`git diff A...B`" is equivalent to
>      "`git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B`". You can omit any one of `<commit>`,
>      which has the same effect as using `HEAD` instead.

Comment: Thanks. My feature branch has been merged into the master branch, and the master branch has evolved several commits since the merge. Can your command work in my case

Comment: what does `..` between the two branches mean?

Comment: @Tim Oops, did I put just two dots? There should be three dots. Corrected.

Comment: what do the three dots mean?

Comment: Your command compares the master branch and my feature branch. My feature branch has been merged into the master branch, and the master branch has evolved a lot since the merge. Does your command compare the latest commit on the master branch and the latest commit on my feature branch? But I want to compare the latest commit on my branch, i.e. the commit on my branch which was merged into the master branch, with respect to the commit on the master branch from which I created my feature branch.

Comment: @Tim I have added that to the answer. Not very strictly, `git diff A...B` means find the commit on the branch `A` from which the branch `B` was started (that commit is called the common ancestor of `A` and `B`) and compare the last commit on branch B with it.